# Why the test 'Assert.AreEqual' has failed when I compare two empty list?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class MyCustomClass:

```
public MyCustomClass
{
    public MyCustomClass()
    {
        MyObject = new List<MyCustomObject>();
    }

    public List<MyCustomObject> MyObject {get; set;}
}
```

In the Test:

```
List<MyCustomObject> aux = new List<MyCustomObject>();
MyCustomClass oClass = new MyCustomClass();
Assert.AreEqual(aux, oClass.MyObject)
```

The test has failed, why? Every property, static member, etc are the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case `Assert.AreEqual` will check to see if the two objects are the same, and they're not.  You should use [`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead, which will return true if the two "have the same elements in the same order and quantity."

Comment: +1 Did you start answering before question was asked :) ? Side note: `AreEqual` overrides for string actually compare values instead of "objects are the same".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `AreEqual` just calls the `Equals` method of the objects.  The `string` implementation of `Equals` compares the values, and the `List` implementation compares the references.  Each class can do whatever it wants; it's not like there is special support for string or anything like that.

Comment: @Servy, Good point. I'd avoid using "same" for statement about comparing objects in C#/.Net - but instead explicitly say "same reference"/"same via operator ="/"same via Equals"... (BTW I like you deleted your answer)

Answer (score 4):

As [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12606248/13627), two lists of same type with zero elements are not considered equal.

The reason behind this, is that `AreEqual` actually calls `aux.AreEqual(oClass.MyObject)`, using the objects own equality implementation. Because this is not overridden for `List<T>`, it falls back to the implementation in `Object`, which is a simple reference equality check. Those two lists are clearly not the same reference, and therefore, they are not considered equal.

Because the `Equals` method exists and is virtual on `Object`, your own classes can override `Equals` in order to provide another concept for equality than reference equality. This is done on objects like `String`, which compare equal even for different references, if the data is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I decompiled `Assert.AreEqual` (which is in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`  GAC assembly) using [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and found that `Assert.AreEqual(aux, oClass.MyObject)` will ultimately result in the following call where `aux` is `expected` and `oClass.MyObject` is `actual`:

```
object.Equals((object) expected, (object) actual)
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) for the static `object.Equals(Object, Object)` we read:

> The static Equals(Object, Object) method indicates whether two
>   objects, objA and objB, are equal. It also enables you to test objects
>   whose value is null for equality. It compares objA and objB for
>   equality as follows:
>
> It determines whether the two objects represent the same object
>   reference. If they do, the method returns true. This test is
>   equivalent to calling the ReferenceEquals method. In addition, if both
>   objA and objB are null, the method returns true.
>
> It determines whether either objA or objB is null. If so, it returns
>   false.
>
> If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and
>   neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result.
>   This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method,
>   this override is called.

Now, `List<T>` is known to be a reference type, and we know that neither of the two lists you are comparing are null, so the final comparison between your two objects will be

```
expected.Equals(actual)
```

Since `List<T>` does not override `Equals`, it uses the base object implementation, which performs reference comparison, and thus fails (`expected` and `actual` were "newed" separately).

What you want is *structural comparison*, i.e. the pair-wise equality of the elements in your lists. See @ReedCopsey answer for the correct assertion for that ([`CollectionAssert.AreEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).